# How to format numbers and cell in grid.table?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having a lot of problems formatting a table.

I would like to have multiple different formats within this table.

Given the dataframe:

```
obs=c(1,2,3,4)
n=c(30, 40, 1000, 33333)
s=c(0.11111, 0.44444, 0.55555, 0.8888)
m=c(222.222, 4444.5555, 5565.223, 323423.09808)

df = data.frame(obs,n,s,m)

Tdf  = setNames(data.frame(t(df [,-1])), df [,1])

grid.table(Tdf)
```

I would like to have columns different colours.

ie. blue, brown, blue, brown

row n to have comma format such as: 30, 40, 1,000, 33,333.

row s to have only two places after the decimal: 0.11, 0.44, 0.56, 0.89

row m to have only two places after the decimal, and comma format, plus colour blue: 222.22, 4,444.56, 5,565.22, 323,423.10

In addition, is it possible to format a individual cell different?

I'm likely going to place a table like this blow a boxplot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
obs=c(1,2,3,4)
n=c(30, 40, 1000, 33333)
s=c(0.11111, 0.44444, 0.55555, 0.8888)
m=c(222.222, 4444.5555, 5565.223, 323423.09808)

df = data.frame(obs,n,s,m)

Tdf  = setNames(data.frame(t(df [,-1])), df [,1])

# transpose for formatting
x <- t(Tdf)
mode(x) <- 'character'
x[, 'n'] <- formatC(as.numeric(x[, 'n'])
    , big.mark = ','
    , digits = 0
    , format = 'f'
    )
x[, 's'] <- formatC(as.numeric(x[, 's'])
    , digits = 2
    )
x[, 'm'] <- formatC(as.numeric(x[, 'm'])
    , digits = 2
    , big.mark = ','
    , format = 'f')

require (gridExtra)
grid.table(t(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1.- ALL together

```
tabla1<-data.frame(x=c("a","b","c","d"), y=c(1000,1200.3,245332.3,2212))
grid.newpage()
grid.table(format(tabla1, decimal.mark = ",", big.mark = "."))
```

2.- BY COLUMNS

```
grid.newpage()
tabla1<-data.frame(x=c(0.1234,0.23456,0.34567,0.45678), y=c(1000,1200.3,245332.3,2212))
tabla1$x<-format(tabla1$x, digits = 2, decimal.mark = "_")
tabla1$y<-format(tabla1$y, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",")
grid.table(tabla1)
```